# can we issue create ssl certificate under Root CA does not have Extended key use(Server Authentication)

Tags: ssl, cryptography, root-certificate

I have create one Root Certificate,Intermediate CA and SSl Certificate with below attribute.

**Root Certificate:**

Extended Key Usage    (Client Authentication, TimeStamping)

**Intermediate CA**

Extended Key Usage    (Server Authentication,Client Authenitcation TimeStamping)

**SSL Certiticate.**

Extended Key Usage    (Server Authentication,Client Authenitcation TimeStamping)

I am getting below error in chrome(Img Attached) but same is working fine in firefox ,although i have added both Root and Intermediate CA in Microsoft trust store.

[SSL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtZfL.png)

I did't include Server Authentication in Root Certificate as an extended key.Is there any  way to create ssl certificate under this root .Please help

Comment: The extended key usage is not the problem in my opinion. My guess that the problem lies somewhere else in the certificates but it is impossible to reproduce the problem (and thus help) without having access to the specific certificates (and maybe keys) which cause the problem.

Comment: But if we use Extended Key Usage (Server Authentication) in root certificate  then we able to create valid ssl certificate under that root.

Comment: Sandeep, this is one of many *off topic* posts that you have created. You may want to read the help center - especially [*what topics can I ask here*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The few questions that have been answered have not been accepted by you; you only seem to react with more questions, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

No.  If a CA certificate (root or intermediate) contains an Extended Key Usage extension then issued certificates can only have a subset of those EKUs (unless the CA's EKU has the "any usage" EKU).

Generally a root certificate won't have the EKU extension (good for all purposes), and if the intermediate is owned by the same company it frequently won't have an EKU extension, either.  If the intermediate CA is an issuance partnership then the issuing CA will frequently constrain the subordinate CA.

For example, the TLS certificate for www.microsoft.com (2018-06-05), where a delegated issuing CA agreement is used:

- www.microsoft.com

  - EKUs: TLS Server Auth, TLS Client Auth
- Microsoft IT TLS CA 4

  - EKUs: TLS Server Auth, TLS Client Auth, OCSP signing
- Baltimore CyberTrust Root

  - (no EKU extension)

Compare with www.wikipedia.org:

- *.wikipedia.org

  - EKUs: TLS Server Auth, TLS Client Auth
- GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2

  - (no EKU extension)
- GlobalSign Root CA

  - (no EKU extension)